# Connect Four game in Javascript - how do I detect a horizontal win?

Tags: javascript

I try to code a Connect Four game and define a winner when 4 pieces are aligned horizontally. I haven't moved to the diagonal part yet, want to get this one first.

**What I try to achieve** - check if the current location (i) and i+6, meaning the next column, same row, have the same player's class.

**Problem** - "Count" never adds up for horizontal victory.

The problematic part starts from *checkForHorizontalVictory.*

Pay attention that I switched for loop to go through allSlots.length, not slots.length, as I want all 42 slots. You'll see the rest.

Anyway, how do I write a code to understand where the player's button is, get the index, and check if index+6 (and later -6) has the same class?

```
var currentPlayer = "player1";
var column = $(".column");
var allSlots = $(column.children());
function switchPlayer() {
    if (currentPlayer === "player1") {
        currentPlayer = "player2";
    } else {
        currentPlayer = "player1";
    }
}
$(".column").on("click", function (e) {
    var col = $(e.currentTarget);
    var slots = col.children();


    for (var i = slots.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentSlot = slots.eq(i);
        var hole = currentSlot.children();

        if (!hole.hasClass("player1") && !hole.hasClass("player2")) {
            hole.addClass(currentPlayer);

            var verticalVictory = checkForVerticalVictory(slots);
            var horizontalVictory = checkForHorizontalVictory(slots);

            if (verticalVictory) {
            }
            if (horizontalVictory) {
            }

            switchPlayer();
            break;
        }
    }
});


function checkForVerticalVictory(slots) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
        console.log(slots.length, "this is slots length in vertical");
        var currentSlot = slots.eq(i);
        var hole = currentSlot.children();

        if (hole.hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        console.log(count, "this is count!");

        if (count == 4) {
            alert("you won! ");
            return true;
        }
    }

    console.log("no wins yet ❌");

    return false;
}

function checkForHorizontalVictory(slots) {
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < allSlots.length; i++) {
        var thisSlot = allSlots.eq(i);
        var thisHole = thisSlot.children(i);

        if (
            thisHole.hasClass(currentPlayer) && allSlots.eq(i + 6).hasClass(currentPlayer)
        ) {
            count++;
            console.log("this is count", count);
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }

        console.log("this is count", count);

        if (count == 4) {
            // 3. If the counter reaches 4 - we have a win
            alert("you won! ");
            return true;
        }
    }

    console.log("no wins yet ❌");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Change `var allSlots = $(column.children());` to `var allSlots = column.children();`.

Comment: May I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72425845/edit) your question, and put all the code from github.com/anaptsk/connect-4 into a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) directly in your question.  The snippet editor should take your HTML, JS, and CSS files as-is.  Then all the code for your question is right here instead of elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, since I can't reproduce your issue. But here is what I think:

In the for loop, when it reaches the indexes of the last column and checks for `i + 6` it makes `allSlots.eq(42)` to `allSlots.eq(47)`... And that ends up in a false. So `count` gets resetted to zero.

So change the loop too:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allSlots.length - 6; i++) {
```

I also would move that after the loop. Notice the condition change.

```
if (count <= 4) {
  // 3. If the counter reaches 4 - we have a win
  alert("you won! ");
  return true;
}
```

In short, column #7 was already checked while checking column #6... ;)

---

**EDIT**
Using the full code from [your gitHub](https://github.com/anaptsk/connect-4), I changed the way you are checking the holes of a particular row.

First, pass the slot index to `checkForHorizontalVictory`

So in that function, you know exactly which slot is the starting point of your logic.
You can now get all the *slots* on the same row by filtering `allSlots`.

I used `Arra.from()` to be able to use JS `.filter` with a modulo of the deducted `rowNum`.

Then, recreate a jQuery object from that filtered element list.

```
function checkForHorizontalVictory(currentSlotIndex) {
  var count = 0;
  let rowNum = currentSlotIndex % 6; // rows from 0 to 5, top to bottom
  console.log("rowNum", rowNum);

  // Get a JS array from the jQuery collection
  var thisrow = Array.from(allSlots).filter((s, i) => i % 6 == rowNum);

  console.log("thisrow", thisrow);
  console.log("thisrow length", thisrow.length);

  // Create a jQuery collection from the filtered above
  var $thisrow = $(thisrow)

  for (var i = 0; i < thisrow.length; i++) {
    // var thisrow = allSlots.eq(currentRow);
    console.log(thisrow[i]);

    // Tests to confirm you are checking the right row
    // thisHole.addClass("test");
    // thisHole.text(i)

    if (
      // jQuery object for the specific row
      $thisrow
        .eq(i + 1)
        .children()
        .hasClass(currentPlayer)
    ) {
      count++;
    }

    console.log("this is count", count);

    if (count == 4) {
      console.log("you won! ");
      return true;
    }
  }

  console.log("no wins yet ❌");

  return false;
}
```

[CodePen with your modified code](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JjppePJ?editors=0010)

For fun, uncomment the *Tests to confirm you are checking the right row*.

Comment: super nice of you to respond!
sadly it didn't help. To recreate the problem you can delete the "verticalVictory" part.
I think one of the problems is that for horizontal victory I defined "columns" as everything that has a class called columns, without using an event listener, when for vertical victory check I'm looking at "col"s, that are taken from the event listener function.

Comment: To reproduce, I would need the HTML and the full code. I just noticed this `allSlots.eq(i + 6).hasClass(currentPlayer)` maybe should be `allSlots.eq(i + 6).children().hasClass(currentPlayer)` since the class to check is on the *hole*, not the *slot*.

Comment: If you need inpiration, I also worked on a Connect4 game three years ago. Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rRrOBy?editors=0010).

Comment: thanks again! nothing seems to be working yet.
I uploaded my code here https://github.com/anaptsk/connect-4, in case you prefer to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Check my edit... ;)

Comment: so incredibly nice of you! will test right away!